# Extract values based on timestamps diff conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataset with timestamps and values for each ID. The number of rows, for each ID, is different and I need a double for loop like this:

```
for ids in IDs:
for index in Date:
```

Now, I would like to find the difference between timestamps, for each ID, in these ways:

- values between 2 days
- values between 7 days

In particular, for each ID

- if, from the first value, in the next 2 days there is an increment of at least 0.3 fromt the first value
  OR
- if, from the first value, in the next 7 days there is a value equals to 1.5*first value

I store that ID in a dataframe, otherwise I store that ID in another dataframe.

Now, my code is the following:

```
yesDf = pd.DataFrame()
noDf = pd.DataFrame()

for ids in IDs:
for index in Date:
    if ((df.iloc[Date - 1]['Date'] - df.iloc[0]['Date']).days <= 2):
        if (df.iloc[index]['Val'] - df.iloc[index - 1]['Val'] >= 0.3):
            yesDf += IDs['ID']
        noDf += IDs['ID']
    if ((df.iloc[Date - 1]['Date'] - df.iloc[0]['Date']).days <= 7):
        if(df.iloc[Date - 1]['Val'] >= df.iloc[index]['Val'] * 1.5):
            yesDf += IDs['ID']
        noDf += IDs['ID']


 print(yesDf)
 print(noDf)
```

I get these errors:

```
TypeError: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [sub]
```

and

```
pandas.errors.NullFrequencyError: Cannot shift with no freq
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Edit: my dataframe

```
          Val     ID             Date     
   2199   0.90  0000.0 2017-12-26 11:00:01  
   2201   1.35  0001.0 2017-12-26 11:00:01  
   63540  0.72  0001.0 2018-08-10 11:53:01
   68425  0.86  0001.0 2018-10-14 08:33:01
   42444  0.99  0002.0 2018-02-01 09:25:53
   41474  1.05  0002.0 2018-04-01 08:00:04
   42148  1.19  0002.0 2018-07-01 08:50:00 
   24291  1.01  0004.0 2017-01-01 08:12:02
```

for exampled: for ID 0001.0 the first value is 1.35, and in the next 2 days I don't have an increment of at least 0.3 from the start value, and in the next 7 days I don't have an increment 1.5times the firsrt value, so it goes in the noDf Dataframe.

Also the dtypes:

```
 Val               float64
 ID                object
 Date       datetime64[ns]
 Surname            object
 Name               object
 dtype: object
```

edit:

after the modified code the results are:

```
         Val     ID          Date         Date_diff_cumsum  Val_diff
  24719  2.08  0118.0 2017-01-15 08:16:05       1.0           0.36
  24847  2.17  0118.0 2017-01-16 07:23:04       1.0           0.45
  25233  2.45  0118.0 2017-01-17 08:21:03       2.0           0.73
  24749  2.95  0118.0 2017-01-18 09:49:09       3.0           1.23
 17042  1.78  0129.0 2018-02-05 22:48:17       0.0           0.35
```

And it is correct. Now I only need to add the single ID into a dataframe

Comment: Could you post a few rows of your `DataFrame` as an example and the data types of your columns (the output of `df.dtypes` ) ?

Comment: here is the dataset: https://imgur.com/a/6oVU2sT
the dtypes are:
Val              : float64, 
SSN               : object, 
Date       :datetime64[ns], 
Surname            :object, 
Name               :object , 
dtype: object

Comment: Please, add your dataframe as text in the question. Few lines are enough. We may wish / need to copy-paste it to test our answers, and we cannot do it from an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should work assuming you start from the first value of an ID, so the first timestamp.

First, I added the `'Date_diff_cumsum'` column, which stores the difference in days between the first date for the ID and the row's date:

```
df['Date_diff_cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID').Date.diff().dt.days
df['Date_diff_cumsum'] = df.groupby('ID').Date_diff_cumsum.cumsum().fillna(0)
```

Then, I add the `'Value_diff'` column, which is the difference between the first value for an ID and the row's value:

```
df['Val_diff'] = df.groupby('ID')['Val'].transform(lambda x:x-x.iloc[0])
```

Here is what I get after adding the columns for your sample DataFrame:

```
    Val     ID      Date                    Date_diff_cumsum    Val_diff
0   0.90    0.0     2017-12-26 11:00:01     0.0                 0.00
1   1.35    1.0     2017-12-26 11:00:01     0.0                 0.00
2   0.72    1.0     2018-08-10 11:53:01     227.0               -0.63
3   0.86    1.0     2018-10-14 08:33:01     291.0               -0.49
4   0.99    2.0     2018-02-01 09:25:53     0.0                 0.00
5   1.05    2.0     2018-04-01 08:00:04     58.0                0.06
6   1.19    2.0     2018-07-01 08:50:00     149.0               0.20
7   1.01    4.0     2017-01-01 08:12:02     0.0                 0.00
```

And finally, return the rows which satisfy the conditions in your question:

```
df[((df['Val_diff']>=0.3) & (df['Date_diff_cumsum']<=2)) |
   ((df['Val'] >= 1.5*(df['Val']-df['Val_diff'])) & (df['Date_diff_cumsum']<=7))]
```

In this case, it will return no rows.

```
yesDf = df[((df['Val_diff']>=0.3) & (df['Date_diff_cumsum']<=2)) |
           ((df['Val'] >= 1.5*(df['Val']-df['Val_diff'])) & (df['Date_diff_cumsum']<=7))].ID.drop_duplicates().to_frame()

noDf = df[~((df['Val_diff']>=0.3) & (df['Date_diff_cumsum']<=2)) |
           ((df['Val'] >= 1.5*(df['Val']-df['Val_diff'])) & (df['Date_diff_cumsum']<=7))].ID.drop_duplicates().to_frame()
```

yesDf contains the IDs that satisfy the condition, and noDf the ones that don't

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. But I just noticed that some IDs have timestamps in different times of the year, and I only need the first days, that's why all my dataset is empty after your code. i.e.: if I have some timestamps and some values in a range of 4 weeks, I keep them. Otherwise, if I find some other timestamps, of the same ID, after months or years, I need to delete those rows. How can I modify your code with this? After that, I will store the IDs of the rows in a new dataset

Comment: Also, I think that the cumsum doesn't reset for each ID, in fact at the end of my ids i can find thousands of days. Even in the example the id 2.0 has 349 days between the first 2 dates, but that is the difference from the first measure of the first id

Comment: Thank you for noticing the mistake ! I added a line in my answer, it should fix the problem. For your first question, you can delete the rows that have a 'date_diff_cumsum' that is larger than 30 for example, to keep only the values of the first month. You just need to do `df = df[df["Date_diff_cumsum"]>30]`

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still receiving wrong results. I updated the first question with your results

Comment: Could you post the results you expect with the sample in your initial question ? I have trouble understanding what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: It wasn't an error, sorry. I was using the >30 instead of the <30 and the results were wrong, but it was my fault. Now I only need to copy the single ID into a dataframe, and to write the other IDs into another dataframe

Comment: I just updated my answer, I hope it is what you were looking for!

Comment: Yes, it is perfect! Thank you very much! I noticed only a thing: len(df['ID'].drop_duplicates()) = 3768, len(yesDf) = 171, len(noDf)=3768 and it is the same as the original dataset without duplicates IDs. I don't know where is the issue, because the yesDf and noDf are correct

Comment: That would mean all of the IDs go in noDf. It could be beacause for all IDs, some rows of the DataFrame don't satisfy the condition, so the ID goes in noDf.

Comment: I solved using this code `'noDf = yesDf.append(noDf).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` ': in that way, by joining all the yesDf values into the noDf I get two times the same values, so I drop the duplicates